# How to get (Mountain Lion?) Finder to display ALL files?

Tags: finder, macos, smart-folders

I'm trying to display ALL files, and it doesn't work as I would expect. What am I doing wrong?! Thanks for the help...

Open a Finder window
Select your 'home' - click on your username
Select File > New Smart Folder
Click on + next to Save
Finder displays Kind > Any - At this point I would expect a result, but nothing shows. If I select Kind > Application, I get Applications. Kind > Image gets images... So how do I display Kind > Any (presuming 'Any' is English and means 'All')?

Is the only option to re-install Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's pretty rare to have to create a smart search that would display all files. Kind is set to Any by default, and it wouldn't make sense to start searching for all files after adding a Kind filter.

If you actually want to create a smart search that displays (a large percentage of) all files, you could try setting File visibility to Visible or Invisible:

[image]

It took several minutes for Finder to search for all files, during which it used over 100% CPU.

Even though system files are included, the results include less than half of all my files, which is probably at least partially because Spotlight doesn't index all files.

Comment: So it is reasonable that Kind > Any shows nothing? It doesn't even show 'some'.

Comment: You're right, it might be clearer if it was something like not specified or empty instead of any. But it also makes sense that Finder doesn't start searching for all files in those cases where the user didn't probably intend it.